# How to access json in python

Tags: python, json, object

I am trying to access json object in python and I am running through different errors

this is the data

```
value =    '{"0":{"created":"05-16-13","counter":3},"1":{"created":"05-17-13","counter":1},"2":{"created":"05-18-13","counter":1}}'

I will like to get 
"05-16-13","counter":3
"05-18-13","counter":1
I did

for info in value:
     print info['counter']

I keep getting a type error, any help?
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: where is the error ?

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert it into a Python dictionary:

```
import json

value = '{"0":{"created":"05-16-13","counter":3},"1":{"created":"05-17-13","counter":1},"2":{"created":"05-18-13","counter":1}}'

d = json.loads(value)

for key, info in d.items():
    print info['counter']
```

The error you were getting before was because string objects should be indexed by integers.

Let's take a completely different string and see why:

```
'abcd'[0]  # 'a'
'abcd'['xyx']  # What does this even mean? TypeError!
'{"0":{"created":"05-16-13","counter":3}"}'['couter']  # TypeError for the same reasons.
```

Comment: I win by 7 seconds. ;)

Comment: I get TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @AbidemiOni Oops. A python `dict.items` returns a list-like of the key and info. I fogot the key. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a json library that you can import and use in Python. You can see docs for [Python 3 here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and Docs for [Python 2 here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

```
import json

value = '{"0":{"created":"05-16-13","counter":3},"1":{"created":"05-17-13","counter":1},"2":{"created":"05-18-13","counter":1}}'

value = json.loads(value)
print(value[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `value` is a string. You should parse the json in it to access to its elements:

```
import json
value = json.loads('{"0":{"created":"05-16-13","counter":3},"1":{"created":"05-17-13","counter":1},"2":{"created":"05-18-13","counter":1}}')

for info in value.items():
    print info['counter']
```